# Access log for particular form library

Tags: infopath, auditing, logging, form-library

We are using SP2010 with InfoPath 2010. On a particular form library, we want to log the activities for all users. Whenever a user click on the form, the username, time, file path should be logged for audit purpose.

Our existing content database have stored too much data. (size around 350GB) As we can foresee the log will occupy a large amount of data, we want to avoid writing the log to the content database.

I think it is easy to write some JS and add entry to a list (on a new contentDB). However we have around 500 users with 10000 forms in library. The log size will be too large for a list.

May I have your advice to setup a light weight logging on particular library?

Answer (score 1):

Before auditing, the Reporting feature under Site Collection Feature should be activated.
Under Site Actions -> Site Settings -> Site Collection Administration -> Site Collection Features -> Reporting

If you cannot find the Site collection policies option under Site Settings ->Site Collection Administration then you must enable the Library and Folder Based Retention Feature.
Under Site Actions -> Site Settings -> Site Collection Administration -> Site Collection Features -> Library and Folder Based Retention

To start tracking who and when has viewed / downloaded, etc.., the documents, first you have to create a Site Collection Policy as mentioned below.
Site Actions -> Site Settings -> Site Collection Policies

Create new policy -> Provide Name and check the box for Enable Auditing Select Events you would like to audit -> Click OK

Then, you have to setup the Document Library / List that you would like to audit
Set up the Document Library / List which requires auditing. Go to List Settings or Library Settings of the List / Document Library you would like to audit.

Click on Information Management Policy Settings. Select the content type that you want to set the policy for auditing. Under use site collection policy of that particular content type, select the policy you had defined in first step and click OK.

Note: That’s it - from this point your library / list is set for auditing - any actions will be logged.

For review:
Go to Site Actions -> Site Settings - > Site Collection Administration ->Audit log Reports.

Comment: Sorry that I have not mention in my question. Our content DB is about 350GB size. It is quite over the suggested threshold 200GB. Knowing the log will be written to the same contentDB, it seems not an option for us.